# how to avoid pushing of values pushed to array when radio button value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

[My plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/R4mdZr/)

how to avoid duplication value get pushed into array when radio button changed ?

if i change the radio button value to other radio button value previously selected values are of pushing into array

**My Code**

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function(clickedItem) {
    //console.log(clickedItem)
    var value = clickedItem;
      var index = $scope.selected_ingrediants.indexOf(value);
      if (index === -1) {
        $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
      } else {
        $scope.selected_ingrediants.splice(index, 1);
      }

  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: According to your code, if value already exists in array, it would be removed, otherwise added, therefore it should never have duplicates. What is the problem?

Comment: check my plunker if i change the radio button the previously selected radio button value is also pushing to ` $scope.selected_ingrediants = [];`

Comment: can you get it?

Comment: indexof() will work on a flat array of objects like ['a,'b'] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf. But you are using objects of array. You need to loop to find the index of the exisiting object in the array.

Comment: how to avoid previously selected values to array ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be simpler:

```
if (!$scope.selected_ingrediants.includes(value)) {
  $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
}
```

This uses the [Array 'includes' method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Just to add though, @alexandru's comment is valid, it should work as it is.

Comment: Check the support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: People still use Internet Explorer (crazy I know)

Comment: O.M.G. @AndFisher I'd best be digging out my Commodore 64 then

Comment: These are real concerns when you are trying to deliver professional standard code.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore js can help you easily

```
  var arr = [4,16,9,12,3,4,6,16,9];
  var arrayWithUniqueValues = [];
  _.each(arr,function(item){
       if(!_.contains(arrayWithUniqueValues,item)){
       arrayWithUniqueValues.push(item);
    }
  });

 console.log(arrayWithUniqueValues) //returns [4,16,9,12,3,6]
//For your Example
$scope.toggleSelection = function(clickedItem) {
_.contains($scope.selected_ingrediants,clickedItem) ?
        $scope.selected_ingrediants.splice(index, 1) : 
               $scope.selected_ingrediants.push(value);
}
```

Comment: Overkill for such a task